# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - making fields required

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I had a basic CRUD API which saves a model to a MongoDB which was working fine.

The model looks like the below:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Configuration
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Parameter Name")]
    [Required]
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parameter Value")]
    [Required]
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And my action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Create")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResult>> Create(Configuration configuration)
{
        try
        {
            var res = await _configurationRepository.Add(configuration);
            // DO OTHER STUFF
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling stuff
        }
}
```

When I ported this code to .NET 6, I try the above through Postman, but I get this error:

> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "The Id field is required."

Any idea why this happens? The same happens for string fields too. This is just an example basically most of my actions doesn't work due to this change.

Answer (score 29):

This is due to some model validation changes in ASP.Net 6 (Non Nullable Reference types)

Was able to resolve this by doing the below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

Comment: This supresses all required annotations for all members. Might want to be careful disabling.

Comment: I think it only does it for implicit required attributes. not explicit

Answer (score 18):

2 possible workarounds:

**Workaround 1**

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

**Workaround 2**

or change all string types to string? from the Configuration class.

**Extra Note**

Additionally - `AddControllersWithViews()` may be called with this same options setting.
For example:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The string? refers to dot net 6 introducing explicit nullability for things that were already implicitly nullable. His answer refers to making the strings explicitly nullable by suffixing the type with a question mark. Hence nullable string. There isn't anything wrong with his answer as far as I can see.

Answer (score 12):

There are 3 options to resolve this. You could try any one of these to make it work:

1. Check whether your csproj file has the entry `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`. If yes, remove it .
2. Change `public string Id { get; set; }` to `public string? Id { get; set; }`

3.Add this line into Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

--Cheers

Comment: In the first option, I cleared the error. Thank you.

Comment: Great scott #1 worked for me as well. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `[BsonId]` requires the string to set.

For reference see the source code:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Attributes/BsonRequiredAttribute.cs

You should create a different model for your endpoint and map that model to your datamodel and populate the `Id` field with a value.

Comment: it does, when saving to the MongoDB. but not in the model. also it works fine with .net 5